# Learning from Images in openai gym: memory leak or offscreen glfw issue with render function

Tags: python-3.x, memory-leaks, glfw, openai-gym, torchvision

I am trying to learn a control policy from images in openai gym. My code is very strait forward, however I am for some reason incurring HUGE memory requirements that continue to grow as my code runs. My setup is basically the following:

```
downsample_obs = torchvision.transforms.Compose([
        torchvision.transforms.ToPILImage(),
        torchvision.transforms.Resize((resize,resize), interpolation=2),
        torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()
    ])
env = gym.make('Hopper-v2')
state = env.reset()
observation = downsample_obs(env.render(mode='rgb_array')).detach()
for t in range(1000):
    next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
    observation = downsample_obs(env.render(mode='rgb_array')).detach()
    memory.push(state, np.array([action]), mask, next_state, reward, stored_observe)
    if done:
        break
update_model(memory) ...
```

I have removed everything around the render function and am just calling calling env.render(mode='rgb_array') t times, and I am still maintaining this issue. I assumed that it was because the environment was not being closed, but when I include proper initializations / closures of the environment after each interaction, the memory requirement only increases. I also get the following message everytime I call make:

```
Creating offscreen glfw
```

I have tried various libraries to diagnose a memory leak such as gc and 
SummaryTracker from pympler.tracker. but neither report anything in memory. This has been extremely frustrating, and any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, and thanks in no small part to a collaborator, I found out that the window renderer (glwf) was allocating memory for each window, detaching the monitor from the window, but not destroying the window. Thus this info was never cleaned up. In order to fix this issue, I added the following:

```
import glfw
def f():
   ....
   something that calls .render()
   ....
   glfw.terminate()
```

This forces python to deallocate and garbage collect correctly. Phew.